# Disable future dates in Android date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

Hello All:
How to disable future dates in DatePickerDialog in Android.

I am using following implementation.
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-datepicker-dialog-example

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: I tried to answer this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157401/android-date-picker-should-not-accept-current-date-and-future-dates/7159304#7159304

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to call getDatePicker().[setMaxDate(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29) on your DatePickerDialog to set today as your max date.  You can update the function with the same name from the snippet you posted.

Note the DatePickerDialog is the object that I referenced in the Android Docs from the link I posted.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        //start changes...
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        return dialog;
        //end changes...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, please can you tell me where I can put this code to work? I mean in which function I should put this? I am referring to the code which I posted in the question.

Comment: Nicholas, getDatePicker() method is available in API level 11, but my application is targeting API 7+, is there any way to do this in API level 7?

Comment: I am not seeing a quick way to do this.  Perhaps you will have to create your own CustomDatePicker.

Comment: I added a check in the function to show a toast to the user if he is selecting future dates. :)

Comment: In API 21, my date picker does not let me pick a date greater than this month. This month's days after today are grayed out. But I'm still able to pick a grayed out date...