# android date picker

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I want to restrict the past dates should be disabled  and date date picker has to show next one month future  dates how can i modify the program

```
package com.sample.DatePickerExample;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatePickerExampleActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mDateDisplay;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.date_picker);
    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
    pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);


    updateDisplay();
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
            mDateSetListener,
            mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        break;
    }
}   
private void updateDisplay() {
    mDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based so add 1

        .append(mDay).append("-")
        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
        .append(mYear).append(" "));
}
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
         mDay = dayOfMonth;
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;

        updateDisplay();
    }
};
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421874/how-to-get-the-date-set-in-the-datepicker-widget-in-android/7961268#7961268 refer this link

Comment: Provide validation instead of disabling dates And also don't use Date Picker dialog, as it is deprecated, use DateDialogFragment or an alert dialog with datepicker in it

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,you may use [DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157401/android-date-picker-should-not-accept-current-date-and-future-dates) widget to do that.It has inbuilt methods for setting a range.

But since you're using a `DatePickerDialog`,You need have a custom implementation.You need to programmatically change the selected date back to default when an undesired date is selected.

Follow this code:

```
public class MyDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog{

private Date maxDate;
private Date minDate;

public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);        
    init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}

public MyDatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear,    int dayOfMonth) {
    super(context, theme, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}

private void init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(1970, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
    minDate = cal.getTime();

    cal.set(3000, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
    maxDate = cal.getTime();

    cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
}

public void onDateChanged (final DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day);
    Date currentDate = cal.getTime();

    final Calendar resetCal = cal; 
    if(!minDate.before(currentDate) ){
        cal.setTime(minDate);
        view.updateDate(resetCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), resetCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), resetCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }else if(maxDate.before(currentDate)){
        cal.setTime(maxDate);
        view.updateDate(resetCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), resetCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), resetCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }       
}

public void setMaxDate(Date date){
    this.maxDate = date;
}

public void setMinDate(Date date){
    this.minDate = date;
}   }
```

Credits to the [original working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836596/1221203) by Herrmann