# Disalble date in DatePicker Android

Tags: android, datepicker

In registration, the user must indicate his birthday. So he should choose a date from a DatePicker. 
Is it possible to not showing the dates > actual date in the DatePicker ?

```
private void showDatePicker()
{
    DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();

    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    date.setArguments(args);

    date.setCallBack(ondate);
    date.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
}
```

Comment: then why you want to insert it.?? and if you are not showing it then how user know that he/she enter correct birthday???

Comment: User must see only dates < actual date in DatePicker. This is my question, it is possible to do it please ?

Comment: i cant get you.. explain proper

Comment: In DatePicker, the user can see only the dates < actual date. For example, today is 11/12/2013. This is the Max. So, user see only date < than 11/12/2013 in DatePicker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116920/disable-future-dates-in-android-date-picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setMaxDate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29) of `DatePicker`.

You don't show what your `DatePickerFragment` is but if it's some kind of wrapper for `DatePickerDialog`, you can access the `DatePicker` with [`getDatePicker()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#getDatePicker%28%29) (requires API level 11).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this with condition using Date class's after / before method. Check below Ex:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth,
                cday);
    }
    return null;
}
private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // onDateSet method
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        Date currentDate = new Date();

        Date date = new Date(year - 1900, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        if(currentDate.after(date)){
            Log.d("System out", "True: Current date: "+currentDate +"  Selected date: "+date);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "kindly select a valid date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    }
};
```