# how to disable future dates in datepicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I am suing a date picker in my project,but I am dont want future dates to be enabled to select:-

I also used the answer in the link,

[Disable future dates in Android date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116920/disable-future-dates-in-android-date-picker)

but it does not work for me,
I am using android studio 2.2.3,and my api is 22.

> ```
> public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
>     DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
>     newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
> }
>
> public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
>         DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
>
>     @Override
>     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
>         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
>         int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
>         int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
>         int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
>
>         // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
>         return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
>
>     }
>
>     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
>
>         ddate.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
>
>
>
>
>
>     }
>
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you added that sample code of "maxDateRange" in your code but didn't call it. Just replace your code given above with this:

```
public void showTruitonDatePickerDialog(View v) {
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    return dialog;


}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    ddate.setText(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);





}

}
```

Hope it will work!